# Arquivo JS no ASP Net Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Criei um projeto ASP Net Core seguindo o padrão MVC, no projeto existe a pasta **wwwroot** que contém as **imagens, o css e o javascript** do mesmo. Na pasta javascript possui dois arquivos, um acima com o nome de **"site.js"** e outro com o nome de **"site.min.js"**, fiz uma mask e coloquei no segundo arquivo (site.min.js) porém ao tentar trazer ele para view usando o seguinte código não obtive sucesso:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/site.min.js"></script>
```

Gostaria de saber se os arquivos possuem hierarquia por um estar dentro do outro e por isso não funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Os arquivos não estão "um dentro do outro". O visual studio apresenta dessa forma para indicar que o .min.js está relacionado ok o js de cima. Esse comportamento pode ser desativado.

Comment: Sobre essa funcionalidade: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2019

Answer (score -2):

Esse "min" se trata de arquivo minifier, ele é configurável pelo bundleconfig.json. Dentro dessa configuração você informa qual ou quais arquivos que você deseja "minificar" (reduzir o tamanho) e qual o nome que o minificado vai ter. Sendo assim você precisa alterar somente o "site.js" e ao compilar o mesmo é empacotado e transformado no "site.min.js".

Mais detalhes aqui: [Empacotar e reduzirr ativos estáticos no ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-5.0)